# Using Direct2D from Xaml and C# (using SharpDX)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, direct2d, sharpdx

This question is about the Direct2D / XAML interop helpers `ISurfaceImageSource` and `IVirtualSurfaceImageSource`.

The samples I've seen about these two helpers, such as [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Magazine-Sample-2a657289) one, are in C++.

**Question:** I'd like to render to these in C# using SharpDX. How can I do so?

(It is OK if there is a little C++ just at the API boundary - C# cannot consume the Direct2D interfaces directly.)

Note: I already understand the other XAML interop helpers like `SwapChainPanel`, so please provide answers relating to `ISurfaceImageSource` and `IVirtualSurfaceImageSource` only.

Comment: look into SharpDx I had a great experience with it

Comment: Yes, I use SharpDX extensively and I've updated the post to indicate that this question involves using SharpDX. I haven't found any samples that show how to use these two helpers with SharpDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the SharpDX samples include a [ported C#/SharpDX version](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/StoreApp/XAML%20SurfaceImageSource%20DirectX%20interop%20sample) of this [C++ Windows SDK sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SurfaceImageSource-58f7e4d5) that shows exactly how to do this. Great.